# C++ duplicate symbols

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, duplicates

(Mac)

I've tried namespaces, include guards, pragma once, etc.

Basically, this is the structure:

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(Game Game/main.cpp Game/rtexture.cpp)
```

Game/main.cpp

```
#include "cleanup.h"

//...
cleanup(foobar);
```

Game/rtexture.cpp

```
#include "cleanup.h"

//...
cleanup(foobar);
```

cleanup.h

```
//various includes

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void cleanup(T *t, Args&&... args){
    //Cleanup the first item in the list
    cleanup(t);
    //Recurse to clean up the remaining arguments
    cleanup(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
/*
 * These specializations serve to free the passed argument and also provide the
 * base cases for the recursive call above, eg. when args is only a single item
 * one of the specializations below will be called by
 * Cleanup(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ending the recursion
 * We also make it safe to pass nullptrs to handle situations where we
 * don't want to bother finding out which values failed to load (and thus are null)
 * but rather just want to clean everything up and let cleanup sort it out
 */
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *win){
    if (!win){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Renderer>(SDL_Renderer *ren){
    if (!ren){ 
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Texture>(SDL_Texture *tex){
    if (!tex){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Surface>(SDL_Surface *surf){
    if (!surf){
        return;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
}
```

If anyone asks, I did take this "cleanup.h" from a tutorial but can't find a way to include it in multiple classes without having it declare duplicate symbols.

```
Home at cruz45488-y19-MBA13-12 in ~/desktop/sdlworkspace/tmp
$ make
Linking CXX executable Game
duplicate symbol __ZN5RUtil7cleanupI10SDL_WindowJEEEvPT_DpOT0_ in:
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/rtexture.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RUtil7cleanupI12SDL_RendererJEEEvPT_DpOT0_ in:
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/rtexture.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RUtil7cleanupI11SDL_TextureJEEEvPT_DpOT0_ in:
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/rtexture.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5RUtil7cleanupI11SDL_SurfaceJEEEvPT_DpOT0_ in:
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/rtexture.cpp.o
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `#ifndef CLEANUP_H 
#define CLEANUP_H 
#endif` in cleanup.h? If not then you have to use it.

Comment: No, I am using it - sorry for the late reply. As in the below answers, `inline void` works but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Explicit function template specialisations are subject to the One Definition Rule, just as regular functions are. Add `inline` to allow definitions in a header; or define them in a source file, with declarations in the header.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any include guards. Also, because you include this header in multiple `.cpp` files, `#ifdef` is not enugh - you need to use `inline` keyword, that tells linker, that particular function may be defined in more than one translation units.

```
#ifndef CLEANUP_H
#define CLEANUP_H

//includes...

template<>
inline void cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *win){
    if (!win){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
}
template<>
inline void cleanup<SDL_Renderer>(SDL_Renderer *ren){
    if (!ren){ 
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
}
template<>
inline void cleanup<SDL_Texture>(SDL_Texture *tex){
    if (!tex){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
}
template<>
inline void cleanup<SDL_Surface>(SDL_Surface *surf){
    if (!surf){
        return;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
}

#endif /* CLEANUP_H */
```