# Separate definitions of variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, undefined-symbol

**(Final question at the bottom)**

Recently, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946517/c-duplicate-symbols) concerning how I would fix linker errors (on duplicate symbols concerning multiple definitions of a template void.

Because I was using the functions in multiple source files, I was suggested to use the keyword `inline` to allow declarations in the header or put the declarations in a compiled source file.

After I realized that `inline` had some bad repercussions, I put my declarations in a source file.

Now this was okay, except for variadic templates:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void cleanup(T *t, Args&&... args);
```

I found some apparent solutions - but not to variadic templates - use a .tpp file (but it started declaring duplicate symbols again) or keep the source file and add explicit instantiations.

But `void cleanup` has the potential to be used hundreds of combinations of parameters, so I don't want to explicitly instantiate everything.

**Question:**
So, how would I go about either

1. Keeping the variadic template definitions in the source file, OR
2. Putting definitions in a .tpp file without getting duplicate symbols, and ultimately avoid using `inline`?

Examples of duplicate/undefined symbol errors for .tpp declaration and putting the above template definition in a source file respectively.

```
duplicate symbol __Z7cleanupI10SDL_WindowJEEvPT_DpOT0_ in:
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/main.cc.o
    CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Game/RichTools/rtexture.cc.o
```

_

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void cleanup<SDL_Renderer, SDL_Window*&>(SDL_Renderer*, SDL_Window*&&&)", 
referenced from:
cleanQuit() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: You want the compiler to generate instantiations when they are used but you want to automatically discard duplicates? Use `inline` then! You mention that you considered its use but that it had "bad repercussions", but what exactly are those?

Comment: It seems that in your first question you did not understand the answer.The advice to make inline or move to source file was only about your fully specialized functions - these with empty parameter list template <>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice in answer to your first question: to make inline or move to source file was only about your fully specialized functions - these with empty parameter list `template <>`.

So, do that:

Your header file:

```
// This shall be in header - it is not full specialization:
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void cleanup(T *t, Args&&... args){
    //Cleanup the first item in the list
    cleanup(t);
    //Recurse to clean up the remaining arguments
    cleanup(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
// These shall be only declared here, and implemented in source file, 
// treat fully specialized function templates as regular functions
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *win);
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Renderer>(SDL_Renderer *ren);
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Texture>(SDL_Texture *tex);
```

Your source file:

```
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *win){
    if (!win){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Renderer>(SDL_Renderer *ren){
    if (!ren){ 
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Texture>(SDL_Texture *tex){
    if (!tex){
        return;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
}
template<>
void cleanup<SDL_Surface>(SDL_Surface *surf){
    if (!surf){
        return;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
}
```

Comment: But that means I would have to use inline for the 'not specialized' function, as I tried this earlier.

Comment: @Hyperum why do you think so? Just try my advice. For all not fully specialized functions - just they have to be in header files and they can be inline or not inline. C++ linker is removing such duplicates by itself - you do not need to worry.

Comment: @Hyperium - there is also explicit template instantiation way - but as you already observed - it is very unconvienent to use...

Comment: Okay, well, I guess it worked. Right now, I am so confused, because I tried it this way before once but I had to use the keyword `inline` because it was giving me duplicate symbols - so I must have done something wrong. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Hyperum your linker complained only about fully specialized functions: __ZN5RUtil7cleanupI10SDL_WindowJEEEvPT_DpOT0_  is `void RUtil::cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window*)`. Use demangler.com to get demangled versions of your linker symbols...